# Lighting a volume with a bi-color point light

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, light, volumetrics

I would like to light the center of a cylinder volume with a gradient light White -> Red -> Blue radially from the center to the border.

I created the cylinder normally and applied a volume material:

[image: cylinder with volume material]

Then, I created the light as a point and applied a **blend texture** like this:

[image: light with texture]

But I don't get the expected result (the center should be red then white) :

[image: resulting render]

The [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aVOQw-BIf0) where I have seen this method is tagged as **outdated**.

- Do you think it's the reason for why it doesn't work?
- Do you know how to make a colored gradient lighting of a volume ?

*I'm using blender 2.72*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is with the scale of the mapping for the texture.
I made a test using an empty to control the mapping. Changing the scale of the empty or the size on the Mapping controls did the trick.

[image]