# Lighting a volume with a bi-color point light (2)

Tags: texturing, blender-internal-render-engine, light, transparency, volumetrics

This question is a following of  [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28489/lighting-a-volume-with-a-bi-color-point-light)

I would like to light the center of a cylindric volume with a gradient light White -> Red -> Blue radially from the center to the border.

I made a test of the lighting one a plane mesh and get this result (after some settings) :

[image]

The color gradient is OK

Now I renderer the cylindric volume at the same position than the plane.
And I have this result :

[image]

**This is nearly what I want**.

**Nearly**, because I had in idea to see a white glow inside the volume and the outter volume seems to hide the center of the object.

I tried to change the **density**, **reflection**, and **scattering** settings of the volume but I didn't succeed to see the white glow.

Is it possible to give transparency to a volume and see the inside lighting with special settings ? Or not ?

Comment: transparency = density with volumes. If your inside is really white glowing as you claim, make the center more dense and the outside less dense. I am sure you will see the center.

Comment: It would be better not to light the volume with a light but let the volume emit light itself - with an added emission shader. The center could have more strength than outsides and you can control the color easily imho.

Comment: @Jerryno Note that volumes can't actually emit light in BI (as in illuminate other objects)

Comment: @gandalf3 oh this isn't cycles..you are right

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14469/599